# Match a string that is probably surrounded

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How can I match a string that is probably surrounded by `removeme(.*)` but not necessarily?

The expression should be as general as possible so that even for the following two exemplary strings
`removeme(foo (bar)))` and `foo (bar))`
the match should be 
`foo (bar))`
for both cases.

But really this is just an example, it should match `foo` for `foo` and `removeme(foo)` as well as other arbitary strings that are encapsulated by `removeme()`.

`(?:^removeme\(|^)(.*?)(?:\)$|$)` unfortunately returns `foo (bar)` for `foo (bar))`

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/s3UmVN/1)?

Comment: If I knew that the string was `foo (bar))` I would not need regexp. I will make my question more clear.

Comment: What about https://regex101.com/r/s3UmVN/2 ?

Comment: The `foo (bar))` is really just meant as an example... I just want to have a string without the `removeme()` if it is present.

Comment: Is it going to happen inside a larger block of text?

Comment: That should do then: https://regex101.com/r/s3UmVN/3 let me know...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler version based on the solution given by @JorgeCampos: https://regex101.com/r/s3UmVN/4

`(?:removeme\()(.*)(?:\))`